# Javascript/jQuery to resize randomly the pictures on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Instead of creating thumbnails for my images, I would like to show the original images in my page. For viewing purposes, I still need to resize these images but instead of adding a `width:200px` on them, I want to display each image in a div container but with size randomly chosen from three choices.

These 3 types of div containers (and therefore the images appearance) will have 3 different sizes, all with the same width. 300x100, 300x200, 300x400.

Of course, upon refresh, the images may have a different size now.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set each height this way:

```
var heights = [100, 200, 400];
var height = heights[Math.ceil(Math.random()*3)-1];
```

I guess you would want to iterate through the containers...

```
var heights = ["100px", "200px", "400px"];
$(".container").each(function(i,e) {
    var height = heights[Math.ceil(Math.random()*3)-1];
    $(e).css('height', height);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added it in a http://jsfiddle.net/uJZzT/ can you please take a look?

Comment: @Kaoukkos here's the updated Fiddle, hope that helps ... http://jsfiddle.net/DMwnf/  (I fixed a mistake-- the iterator should update using *css*, not *attr*.)

Comment: I have just accepted your answer. Thank you, again. One last question, as more images are shown ( http://jsfiddle.net/DMwnf/1/ ) the more empty spaces will appear. What is a method that will allow the divs to fill the gaps ?

Comment: @Kaoukkos maybe use separate vertical containers for each column?  http://jsfiddle.net/DMwnf/1/